# A Warning Error of Response with BEPL SOAP Connection with SAAJ

Tags: java, web-services, soap, saaj

I am trying to consume `IBM BPEL` web service, which is published on a live server and consumer using core java, working fine but the code have a warning message:

> Dec 10, 2013 10:18:31 AM
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
>   WARNING: SAAJ0014: Invalid reply message. Content length of reply was
>   zero.

**NOTE:** As designed this web service does not reply anything (response is empty). How can I disable calling party `SAAJ client` not to expecting a reply from the web service response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that [BPEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Execution_Language) has nothing to do with the web service part. From your message I understand that when you call the web service from your client, the response is empty. Therefore, the probable cause could be in the following points:

1. *The specific web service function gets nothing from the business logic layer to return.*
   You have to debug using breakpoints to find if this is true.
2. *The web service function gets something from the business logic layer but it returns nothing due to an error in the specific function*. You have to debug using breakpoints to find if this is true. Maybe the flow control of the function has a bug. Or maybe a data serialization exception throws and gets lost.
3. *The web service endpoint is not configured properly*. Double check the web service endpoint configuration. IP, port, credentials, authorization. Perhaps the web service is configured to return nothing when an anonymous user is calling it.
4. *The client calls another endpoint*. Double check that the client executes the correct request. Try using another client (eg [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/)) to see if it gets the same response. If the response is not the same, then the problem is on the client side.

You have the setup and the code, so you have to find out what is going wrong.

Hope I helped!